# writing query results to a partitioned table

Tags: google-bigquery

I have a query that returns results with dates.

Is it possible to write the results of this query into a (previously created) partitioned table without having to re-run the query for each date?

This ***doesn't work*** (adds all rows under today's partition), but hopefully explains what I'm trying to do:

```
SELECT
   timestamp(dt) as _PARTITIONTIME
   , *
FROM [foo.some_view]
```

I'm specifying as a destination an empty partitioned table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible to write ... ?

Nope. It is not. Yet.
But looks like it is close to be available

You can "monitor" [Field based partitioning](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/65440943) for details